# Adding addresses to ActiveDirectory with Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, windows-server-2003, active-directory

We use a Windows 2003 server and XP stations.

The server's LDAP is working ok, as I am able to retrieve the addresses it contains with Thunderbird.

I'd like to be able to ADD an address to the server's book (the address of a new contact that freshly wrote me, for example) directly from Thunderbird, but that doesn't seem possible.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Contact object in Active Directory if you had sufficient rights in the directory, but I would consider that unlikely.